# AJAX causes Jump to Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I do know this is a duplicate but I've tried placing `e.preventDefault`, and it still jumps.

```
$(".a-result").click(function(e) {
    <some code....>

    $.post(result + "/fineart/show", {id: $artwork_id})
        .done(function(data){
            $rowBeginner.before(data);
    });

});
```

Any help on how to stop AJAX from causing a jump to the top would be greatly appreciated.

`.a-result` is a collection of divs by the way.

**Edit**

```
<div id="results-panel">
    <% @artwork_q.each.with_index do |art, index| %>
        <div class="a-result" id="<%= index %>">
            <div class="a-result-photo">
                <%= image_tag art.photo.url(:small) %>
            </div>
            <div class="a-result-info">
                <%= art.artist.last_first if art.artist.present? %><br>
                <strong><%= art.title %></strong><span class="hidden_id"><%= art.id %></span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In the `#results-panel`, I'm cycling through a rails collection of results, and then place an AJAX div in between one of them.

*Also*, I am using jquery's `offset()` and `offset().top` functions if that would have anything to do with it. I'm using the `offset()` function to test whether the each successive div is offset from the top the same amount, therefore telling me if they're on the same row, since I'm floating all of them. If this is causing it, might there be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: post your related HTML code too

Comment: if you are dealing with click on div nothing in code shown would cause problems like page jumping to top. Ajax doesn't do anything in the UI....it's only what you do with responses that can change anything

Comment: Is there any anchor tag inside div by any chance?

Comment: Now that you  added details about using offsets you need to show that code. Also a  demo would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you clear data in html that is already displayed before calling Post request? 
Because clearing data will cause your html page height less than browser height that results in scroll to top. And your post request fills data in html page again that makes you feel that post request is causing page to scroll to top.

Comment: commented everything except my statement where I remove data, and realized that was it! Is there a workaround for this now? Can I jump back the number of pixels I removed? or prevent this jumping. But yes the removing of data in html is what's causing this. @chandil03

Comment: Before you clear data get scrollY position and when you write data again in html page in post response set scrollY location to previous value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".a-result").click(function(e) {
    <do whatever you want....>
    return false;
});
```